# TensorFlow -Ignoring visible gpu device

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I have a bug
it says that its **Ignoring the GPU** i installed an **nvidia GPU** just to run my code but i dont get how this **error occurs** any ideas? Here's the full error:

2022-05-04 14:15:13.790089: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1892] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 610, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 2.1) with Cuda compute capability 2.1. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2022-05-04 14:15:13.790450: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Arcomm\AI (Artificial Intelegence) Folder\face_mask_detection\src\face_mask_detection.py", line 4, in 
model=load_model("./model2-009.model")
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 915, in load_partial
raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./model2-009.model\variables\variables
You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Programming, could you share the Tensorflow version?

Comment: In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995707/ignoring-visible-gpu-device-with-compute-capability-3-0-the-minimum-required-cu report a similar problem