# Ignoring visible gpu device with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I tried to install tensorflow GPU in an anaconda enviorement, my hardware and software resources are:

- GPU: Quadro K1100M
- python: 3.10.13
- cudatoolkit: 11.2
- cudnn: 8.1.0
- OS: Windows 11
- Tensorflow: 2.10

Everything goes well, but when I test if tensorflow detects my GPU with tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') it prints this error:

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1976] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Quadro K1100M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
[]

I saw this answer: [Ignoring visible gpu device with compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995707/ignoring-visible-gpu-device-with-compute-capability-3-0-the-minimum-required-cu)

But I don't know if it will solve my problem because I am in Windows 11, the doccumentation says:

- Install GPU support (optional)
  See the Windows GPU support guide to install the drivers and additional software required to run TensorFlow on a GPU.

Then in the the Windows GPU support guide says:

- The following GPU-enabled devices are supported: NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® architectures 3.5, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0 and higher. See the list of CUDA®-enabled GPU cards.
- For GPUs with unsupported CUDA® architectures, or to avoid JIT compilation from PTX, or to use different versions of the NVIDIA® libraries, see the Linux build from source guide. (My case)

Because it says to look on the Linux build from source guide, I don't think that the answer will work on Windows.

So anyone knows if this works or another way to solve the problem or may I change my GPU.

Comment: Looks like support for such old GPUs has been dropped at some point, 3.5 seems to be the oldest they support even when building yourself now.  You could try installing an old version of tensorflow but if you want current features you'd have a lot of work to do.